# Particles appearing at different locations when rendering

Tags: particles

I have set up a Biod particle System to follow a leader. No child particles. However, when rendering the particles seem to be at different places. When going to the first frame the particles seem to not have moved at all even so they are set to start at frame -100 and end at frame 0. I have baked the cache to see if that helps.

This example shows the particles at frame 60.
[image: Particles in Viewport]

[image: Particles in Render]

Comment: show us your blend file.

Comment: Shure Ill just upload it to google drive if thats allright. [Here it is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TNmMK4Xxwgm5CSBbBhM-ESllC8r8R_7w/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try rendering the very first frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have set the visibility of your cube in trash  in viewport to "hidden", but not in render.

so press the filter button

[image]

tap on "disable in render"

[image]

and then mark your cube in trash as "disable in render" too...else it will be rendered.

[image]